# Add class="media_type" when media is inserted into editor

Tags: media-library, editor

I am looking for a way to edit the link that get inserted in the editor when the user choose to add a media. The goal would be to add a class with the media type (pdf) in the link.

I know how to get the mime type but I am not sure which hook to use to retrieve the link before it gets inserted. Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to @amritanshu and @wycks [github's code](https://gist.github.com/wycks/2176359), here is the solution for those in need to add a class with the media type to the attachment url before it gets inserted in the editor :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'epc_add_class_pdf' ) ) :

    function epc_add_class_pdf( $html, $id ) {

        $attachment = get_post( $id );
        $mime_type = $attachment->post_mime_type;

        // I only needed PDF but you can use whatever mime_type you need
        if ( $mime_type == 'application/pdf' ) {
            $src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
            $html = '<a class="pdf" href="'. $src .'">'. $attachment->post_title .'</a>';
        }

        return $html;
}
endif;
add_filter('media_send_to_editor', 'epc_add_class_pdf', 20, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter way to do it (PHP 5.4+):

```
add_filter( 'media_send_to_editor', function( $html, $send_id, $attachment )
{
  $class = wp_check_filetype( $attachment['url'] )['ext'];
  return str_ireplace( '<a href', sprintf( '<a class="%s" href',$class ? $class : 'unknown' ), $html );
}, 10, 3 );
```

where we get the attachment's info from the third input argument.

We could also use the mime type data, from `wp_check_filetype()`, instead of the extension.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not the answer but just the hint.**

`media_send_to_editor` 
should be the hook that should help you. Not sure how but came across this while searching for my problem

I would have commented but still 4 points short, so unable to comment

All the best

Comment: @Pipo My pleasure.. Any idea how to do that for existing  media.                     This will only work when you add new media but not for the existing media.

Comment: I don't think this is the best answer as I don't know much about SQL but I would try to use the REPLACE function of mysql to add a `class` after the end of the `href`. Of course this is kind of a hack and will only works if you can find a similarity in the links you want to replace (for example: replacing `.pdf">` by `.pdf" class="your-class">` in the relevant tables). But this is just an idea...